# Re-define view existing module Dotnetnuke 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

The "Account login" module, which exists in the basic installation of Dotnetnuke 7, has a view that displays the login form.

My question is: What do I have to do to re-define that view (change the login form) in my own Skin?

Comment: Hi Lobo, look at this link on the DotNetNuke community exchange section. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Community-Exchange/Question/2762/Add-Login-Password-on-same-line-in-skin.aspx

Comment: Ok, if login module type, does "mylogin.ascx" file should be in "/DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/myfolder"?

Comment: The login module uses "/DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/DNN/Login.ascx", so you can either change this file to meet your requirements or you can create your own login module. You will just need to keep in mind that the login.ascx file might change when doing dotnetnuke upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke expects that out of the box login module is present on the page that is set as a login page. That means, even if you are using a custom module for login, you have to drop out of the box module inside that page and set the security to allow only for authenticated users.

If this is not what you want to know, please add more details about what you mean by "re-define".